# Why i can't see bioTextView in UITextView in Swift/ UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm learning Swift with UIKit and trying to design a basic UI using UIkit I am stuck in an issue that I can't see the bioTextView text on my UI, What's the problem with my code I have a white background in my screen and a bioTextView text color is black and i can't see it on the screen. I can't see any error in my Xcode and my app build successfully

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isFollowing = false
    var nameLabel = UILabel()
    var profileImageView = UIImageView()
    var followBtn = UIButton()
    var bioTextView = UITextView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        nameLabel.text = "Jeff Bezos"
        nameLabel.textColor = .black
        nameLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(nameLabel)

        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dog")
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        
        followBtn.setTitle("   Follow   ", for: .normal)
        followBtn.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        followBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        followBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
        followBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        followBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        followBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OnPress), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(followBtn)
        
        bioTextView.text = "Hello World,Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World"
        bioTextView.backgroundColor = .blue
        bioTextView.textColor = .black
        bioTextView.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        bioTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bioTextView.isHidden = false
        view.addSubview(bioTextView)
        SetupConstraints()
    }
    
    func SetupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120),
            nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.centerXAnchor),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            followBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerXAnchor),
            followBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30)
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bioTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: followBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            bioTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: followBtn.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func OnPress() {
        if !isFollowing {
            isFollowing = true
            followBtn.setTitle(" Following ", for: .normal)
        } else {
            isFollowing = false
            followBtn.setTitle(" Follow ", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With you `bioTextView` everything is okay.

There is something wrong with the Constraint for the `bioTextView`

disable this temporary:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bioTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: followBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            bioTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: followBtn.centerXAnchor)
])
```

To test the `bioTextView` you can also use the `frame` property on the `bioTextView` like so:

```
bioTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: view.bounds.width - 200.0, height: 200.0)
```

You will need to rework the Constraints for `bioTextView`, if you want to use the Constraint Layout.

Hope this gives you some guidance.

Comment: Giving bioTextView bottom and trailing Anchor fixes the issue